# Java Script - Regex - Password validation with Hebrew characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

I've got an issue with the password validation.
That's my code:

```
function validatePassword(){

    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var re = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;


 if(!password.match(re)){

      producePromt("The password is invalid","commandPasswordPrompt","red");
            return false;

 }
    producePromt("Password is OK","commandPasswordPrompt","green");
            return true;
}
```

It says that its only invalid, So I thought that its because of the regex.
I asked you if you can help with everything here.

Thanks a lot for helpers!

Comment: Can you also tell which password string is coming as invalid?

Comment: Have you tried using something like http://regexpal.com/ to test some sample data?

Comment: http://regex101.com will also give you a text explanation of the parsed regex.

Comment: Looks like your Regex accepts passwords from 6 to 16 characters, and it MUST contain numbers, special characters and not necessarily letters... is that what you wanted?

Comment: The expression above says that your password should be between six and sixteen character long and it should have at least one number, and one special character in order to be valid

Comment: I want that the password will contain: numbers and letter (In English and Hebrew). And the password's length wil be from 8 chars to infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
// At least eight numbers or/and letters of English or Hebrew language
^[a-zA-Z0-9\u0590-\u05FF]{8,}$
```

Or

```
// At least eight characters: one number, one uppercase, one lowercase English letter and one Hebrew letter
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\u0590-\u05FF]).{8,}$
```

Or

```
// At least eight characters: one number and one uppercase of lowercase English or Hebrew letter
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z|A-Z|\u0590-\u05FF]).{8,}$
```

Usage:

```
var p = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z|A-Z|\u0590-\u05FF]).{8,}$/g;
var s = "שלוםWorld2";
if(!p.test(s)){
  console.log("Invalid password!");
}
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kI6qP0/2) | [jsBIn Demo](http://jsbin.com/quqigelu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: The password must contains: English or Hebrew (or together) and numbers. I dont want only numbers or only letters.

Comment: I dont see that it works. I checked in two Regex's testers and nothing works.

Comment: @iYonatan You must be kidding ;) Check the answer again, check the usage and the both demos.

Comment: I think I have an issue with the function. can you check my function and find out the solution because I cant find out. Please help me.

Comment: @iYonatan Paste you function in your question or paste it on jsbin.com and share the link here

Comment: @iYonatan Check your function on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tudesaja/1/edit?html,js,console,output) Just be sure to uncomment commented lines (functions) And its better to use `test` method as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! but I asked for the paasword's ivalidation:
English or Hebrew (or together) and numbers. I dont want only numbers or only letters

For all of the posseble options:
שלום12334
ddfdf123
שלוםhello123
שלוםHELLOworld123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58457/discussion-between-iyonatan-and-hex494d49).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check it twice to make it easy.
For example:

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var re1 = /^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
var re2 = /[0-9]/
var re3 = /[!@#$%^&*]/
if(password.match(re1) && password.search(re2) >=0 && password.search(re3) >=0){
      producePromt("The password is invalid","commandPasswordPrompt","red");
            return false;
} 
producePromt("Password is OK","commandPasswordPrompt","green");
```